# Is there a simple way to select the second to last item in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object, ruby-hash

Is there a simple way to select the second to last item in Ruby? Something similar to like the `nth-child` selector in css?

Here is my code:

```
def pic2
    @pic2 ||= begin
      result = card.attachments&.last&.url # I need this to be changed to select the second to last attachment instead of the last
      if result
        logger_card("Pic found on trello card (#{result})")
        result
      else
        logger_card('No Trello Picture')
        nil
      end
    end
  end
```

I need that third line changed to select the second to last attachment instead of the last

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
result = card.attachments[-2].url
```

Something like that?

Comment: You initially had the [-2] in the wrong place, so I moved it in your answer. Just an FYI. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you use Rails, you can use [`Array#second_to_last`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-second_to_last) method:

```
card.attachments.second_to_last
```

It is just [ActiveSupport syntax sugar](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/83217025a171593547d1268651b446d3533e2019/activesupport/lib/active_support/core_ext/array/access.rb#L98-L103) for `[-2]` that Sergio proposed

You can also use this method in pure Ruby. Just include this part of library in your code:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/access'
```

Answer (score -2):

One thing that also works that I was planning on using before @WesleyBond posted was the following:

```
card.attachments&.reverse[1].url
```